# If $x^c\cap y =x\cap y^c =\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $x^c\cap y =x\cap y^c =\emptyset$

Does it follow that $x=y$, intuitively if feel that it is true but I can't prove it.

Comment: Hint: take this one step at a time. What does $X^C \cap Y = \varnothing$ tell you?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram; that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use capitals when dealing with sets. It's an unwritten convention.

**Claim**: $X^C \cap Y = \emptyset = Y^c \cap X \implies X = Y$

**Proof:** We prove the contrapositive: $X \neq Y \implies X^C \cap Y \neq \emptyset \neq Y^c \cap X$

Suppose $X \neq Y$. Then, assume that  $X \not\subset Y$ . Then, there exists $x \in X$ such that $x \notin Y$. So $x \in X$ and $x \in Y^c$, meaning that $x \in Y^c \cap X$. Hence $Y^c \cap X \neq \emptyset$. In the same way, $Y \not\subset X$ leads to $X^c \cap Y \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: To me (and, I presume, quite often), $A\ne B\ne C$ means $A\ne B\wedge B\ne C$, which is not $\neg(A=B\wedge B=C)$: that would be $A\ne B\vee B\ne C$.

Comment: Ah you are right. Thanks for pointing out. Will edit it once I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Read it out aloud. There are no elements in $Y$ that are not also in $X$ and vice versa. Thus $X=Y$.

Comment: You answer a question you vote to close?